# Update my column status using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I update my data table, in the column status? I've tried using this code and it is not working. I don't know what code to be inserted using my AJAX code. I hope someone will help me with this. Thank you in advance.

[image: The right one.]
[image: The wrong one.]

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btn_edit').click(function(){
            var id = $('#brand_id').val();
            var brand_name = $('#brand_name').val();
            var brand_status = $('#brand_status').val();

            if (brand_status == "Available") {
                brand_status = 1;
            } else {
                brand_status = 2;
            }

            $.ajax({
                url       : 'edit_brand.php',
                method    : 'POST',
                data      : {brand_name : brand_name, brand_status : brand_status, id : id},
                success   : function(response) {
                                $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=brand_name]').text(brand_name);
                                if (brand_status == 1) {
                                    $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=brand_status]').append("<span class='label label-success'>Available</span>");
                                } else {
                                    $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=brand_status]').append("<span class='label label-danger'>Not Available</span>");
                                }
                                $('#modal-edit').modal('toggle');
                            }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Share your edit_brand.php coding And also your html coding

Comment: I really hope you are using prepared statements. Also with what you have,its impossible to get the current brand id or status of the button clicked . You'll need to take care of that

Comment: Ohh, sorry I forgot that thing. Hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, for this line,

```
    $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=brand_status]').children("<span class='label label-success'>Available</span>");
```

You should be using this:

```
    $('#'+id ).children('td[data-target=brand_status]').replaceWith( "<span class='label label-success'>Available</span>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I just want to change the value in my column status just like in my image. I've use span in order the text has a design on it. See my code in the success function, I want it like that but the code is not working. I don't know what code to replace that.

Comment: Based on the code, seems like you need to click the edit button in order to execute the ajax.The ajax will look for "edit_brand.php"
You need to check your console to see if there is any error message after you click "#btn_edit"

You can share your error message here.

Comment: It says "unrecognized operation" using my span. How can I fix that?

Comment: Hmm, for this line,
$('#'+id).children("<span class='label label-success'>Available</span>");

Should u be using append instead? 
http://api.jquery.com/append/ 

Children is only to get
https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: I already use append here, but it will duplicate the value of my column status.

Comment: Hello? I've updated my code and the image of my question. I hope you can help me with that. :(

Comment: you might want to try this line:
"$( '#'+id ).replaceWith( "<span class='label label-success'>Available</span>" );"

Comment: But why is it, it is not inline with my brand name when I update it? But when I refresh it, it is now inline?

Comment: can show me your update code, the html and image for that portion?

Comment: Can send me the html code before and after clicking edit?

Comment: Through a private chat?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `post` ajax request like this -

```
$.post("edit_brand.php",
{
    brand_name : brand_name, brand_status : brand_status, id : id
},
function(data, status){
    $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=brand_name]').text(brand_name);
    if (brand_status == 1) {
        $('#'+id).children("<span class='label label-success'>Available</span>");
    } else {
        $('#'+id).children("<span class='label label-danger'>Not Available</span>");
    }
    $('#modal-edit').modal('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Thank you but, what about my span tag? I want to update my column status using it.

Comment: You can do it in the function. Let me update the snippet.

Comment: I've updated the snippet. But I'll prefer if you change `span` tag based on the response you are getting after calling the ajax request. Also separate your JS and PHP code and return success and failure response from PHP after performing `update` operation.

Comment: Yes, try to change the ajax code and do let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: I've tried it but it is not working. After I click my button the value in the column status is not changing.

Comment: I've also updated my code to the question using your code.

Comment: Use debugger and try to fetch and check what are the values coming in `brand_status` and `brand_name`

Comment: I already did that, the value of my brand_name is "Acer" a string value. Just like in my database. Also in my brand_status is 1 an integer value. Just like my database.

Comment: Just for a testing purpose paste this code `$('#'+id).children("<span class='label label-danger'>Not Available</span>");` in the `else` condition before you are calling ajax request.

Comment: Hello? I've updated my code and the image of my question. I hope you can help me with that. :(

Comment: Don't append the code, change the html using .html() on the element

Comment: The replaceWith solved my problem but I have a new problem when I update it. It is not inline with my brand name, how can I fix that? I've updated the image.

Comment: I've updated the image to my question. The first one is the right alignment, then the second one is not. :(

Comment: It seems to occurring due to wrong DOM manipulation but for now you can apply margin-top using JS in the else part where you are changing the status.